# Copy line, followed by down arrow skips a line on Mac, how to change this behaviour?

Tags: intellij-idea

I select a line of code in IntelliJ using the copy line shortcut, then I press the down arrow, the cursor skips the next line and goes to the third line

ie copy line shortcut on line 1, press down arrow to go to line 2 but I'm taken to line 3.

This behaviour changed with the release of 2021.2 or near.  How to revert to the normal and previous behaviour?

(using Mac)

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269579), please vote for it.

To get back the old behaviour, invoke `Help | Find Action` (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and search for "registry". Invoke the `Registry` action, search for the entry `editor.action.caretMovement.UpDownIgnoreSelectionBoundaries` and enable it.